# $(element:visible) before or after $(this)

Tags: jquery, element, parent-child, visible

How do I determine if `$(element:visible)` is placed before or after `$(this)` in HTML?

My HTML code looks like this

```
<div class="wrapper" style="display:none;">
    <div class="title">1</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">2</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="display:none;">
    <div class="title">3</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="display:none;">
    <div class="title">4</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

When I click on title 2 I want to know if there is visible `$('.wrapper')` before that title.

Comment: I will place it differently... When I, for example, click on title 4 (when it's visible) I want to know if there are visible divs with class "wrapper" placed before that title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you need

```
$(".title").click(function(){
  if($(this).parent().prev().is(":visible")) alert("Previous is visible!")
});
```

This tells you if the previous `.wrapper` (previous to clicked title) is visible.

**EDIT**: This solves your updated question

```
$(".title").click(function(){
  if($(this).parent().prevAll(".wrapper").is(":visible")) alert("Previous is visible!")
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I think better is `.prev('.wrapper')` (for the beginning of the list).

Comment: `$('.wrapper .title').click`, not `$('.wrapper').click` :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. That's not exactly what I need :) I will place it differently... When I, for example, click on title 4 (when it's visible) I want to know if there are visible divs with class "wrapper" placed before that title

Comment: @Goldie: You mean any? Then use `prevAll('.wrapper')`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys :). @Goldie, i've updated my answer to meet your needs

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up. You need to check if there are any visible elements with class "wrapper" prior to clicked element.

If that is it, this should do it.

```
$(".wrapper").click(function() {
  var el;
  el = $(this);
  $(".wrapper:visible").each(function(index) {
    if ( el.get(0) === $(this).get(0) ) {
      alert("There are no visible wrappers prior to this one.");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("There are visible wrappers prior to this one.");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Or:

```
$(".wrapper").click(function() {
  if ( $(this).prevAll(".wrapper:visible").length ) {
    return alert("There is " + $(this).prevAll(".wrapper:visible").length  + " wrappers prior to this one.");
  } else {
    return alert("There are no visible wrappers prior to this one.");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent("div:visible")
```

This will give you a parent only if it is visible.

Comment: But how do you click on an item that is not visible? ;) (I thought the same way at the beginning...)

Comment: Ah I understand - it is not the parent of the clicked item, but the siblings of the parent. So use parent().siblings("div:visible") and it should give you what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').prev().is(':visible');
```

Will get the closest parent with a class `wrapper` meaning even if `$(this)` is deeper inside the wrapper it will still function properly.

Comment: Same here: You cannot click on an item that is not visible. Hence, if you can click the `.title` element, all ancestors must be visible (though it could be that the OP is not aware of that).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.title').click(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().prev('.wrapper:visible').length) {
        console.log('visible');
    } else {
        console.log('not visible');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to see if there is ANY previous visible wrappers...
`$(this).parent().prev(".wrapper:visible").length()`

If you are looking to see if only the previous one before it is visible...
`$(this).parent().prev().is(":visible")`